# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n^2+k}{n^2-k}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

What would you suggest me to do for the following limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\displaystyle\frac{n^2+k}{n^2-k}\right)^n.$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write

$$P=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\displaystyle\frac{n^2+k}{n^2-k}}{e}\right)^n$$

$$\begin{align}\log{P} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left[-1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \log{\left ( \frac{n^2+k}{n^2-k} \right ) }\right ]\\ &=  \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left[-1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left \{ \log{\left ( 1 + \frac{k}{n^2} \right )} - \log{\left ( 1 - \frac{k}{n^2} \right )} \right \}\right ]\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left[-1 + \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k\right ]\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left[-1 + \frac{2}{n^2} \frac{n (n+1)}{2} \right]\\ &= 1\end{align}$$

Note that, in the 3rd equality, I used the fact that $\log{(1\pm y)} \sim \pm y$ as $y \rightarrow 0$.

$$\therefore P=e$$

Comment: How does the third equality follow?

Comment: Taylor expansion of the logs for large $n$.  Note that we can do this because of the fact that the argument never exceeds $1/n$, which is small in this limit.

Comment: @rlgordonma: This is the way I would go. (+1)